# Should stored procedure cached in Mysql

Tags: mysql, caching, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Should stored procedure cached in Mysql? If yes, How long it is stay in cache?

In my case, when I call one stored procedure first time, it is giving me result in 1sec, after that it gives me result in 400ms. And when I am changing some parameters passed to the stored procedure and call first time, same behavior performed. So, I can not understand what happening? Can some one guide me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is the normal behavior of any system that uses a cache :

- at first time execution the results are loaded in cache , thus a small overhead appears
- the following execution will take much less because they are already in cache **BUT** if any input is changed (like in your case : changing some parameters of the stored procedure) then the results that are already in cache are not longer viable so the new results (using the changed inputs) must be put in cache that is why it takes longer

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use 
[Deallocate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deallocate-prepare.html) in the your procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetVenues (TheVenue varchar(22)) 
BEGIN 
SET @s = 'SELECT * FROM Venues WHERE VenueName = ?'; 
SET @v = TheVenue;
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s; 
EXECUTE stmt1 USING @v; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 
END;
```

Other option: `RESET QUERY CACHE;`

If the user you're running as has reload rights. Alternatively, you can defragment the query cache via:

`FLUSH QUERY CACHE;`